# Asp.Net Core Swagger Sort Tags Alphabetically

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-ui

I'm using asp.net core 6 & Swashbuckle.AspNetCore

and I'm using SwaggerAnnotations in my actions

But my Tags Groups are not ordered

Here's my Swagger UI page

[image]

---

My Program.cs :

```
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c => {
  c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo {
    Title = "Api", Version = "v1"
  });
  c.EnableAnnotations();
});

 ....

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI(c => {
  c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Shoppy.WebApi");
  c.InjectStylesheet("/swagger-ui/css/custom.css");
});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I got the solution

I created this Custom DocumentFiler thats sorts the Tags

```
public class OrderTagsDocumentFilter: IDocumentFilter 
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiDocument swaggerDoc, DocumentFilterContext context) 
    {
        swaggerDoc.Tags = swaggerDoc.Tags
             .OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();
    }
}
```

and added it to Program.cs

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c => {
  c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo {
    Title = "Shoppy.WebApi", Version = "v1"
  });
  c.EnableAnnotations();

  c.DocumentFilter<OrderTagsDocumentFilter>();
});
```

Answer (score 7):

Also you can do it using such configuration string

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    c.ConfigObject.AdditionalItems.Add("tagsSorter", "alpha");
    ...
});
```